# Dataset explain method runs out of memory

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark 2.4.4. I have a Dataframe with big (16 stages, 14 of which cached) DAG. When `df.explain(true)` is run, I get OOM errors no matter how big is driver memory (I stopped testing at 16G since actual data size is smaller). I can't remove that `explain` call since it's in a library I have to use. UI seems to have no problem displaying DAG on last job with DF.

Could there be a cycle in DAG? There are no cycles in UI. Or what else could be wrong?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:350)
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:941)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromString(UTF8String.java:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec$$anonfun$sideEffectResult$1.apply(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec$$anonfun$sideEffectResult$1.apply(commands.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.explain(Dataset.scala:484)
    ...
```

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:544)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:692)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:692)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:692)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:692)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:571)
```